# How can we synthesize para-nitrophenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, phenols

During nitration of phenol, both *para*- and *ortho*-nitrophenols will be formed.

[image]

Is there any way in which we can synthesize *para*-nitrophenol  only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always fractionally distillate the two. In this case, since the boiling points have a large difference, simple distillation works as well.

(I'm not too good with "collateral damage" of reactions, so if a reaction affects an extra group that it shouldn't, please let me know)

Otherwise, you can use the [Claisen rearrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claisen_rearrangement) to protect the ortho position.

(I'll see if I can get a chemdrawing software later)

Take phenol, add $\ce{Na+ CH2=CH-CH2-}$ (you may use lithium instead of sodium--easily prepared from $\ce{CH2=CH-CH2-X}$). You will get $\ce{Ph-O-CH2-CH=CH2}$

Heat it, the group migrates to ortho.

[image: enter link description here]

Repeat, and now you have a phenol with two $\ce{CH2=CH-CH2\bond{-}}$ groups at each ortho position.

Now nitrate. The nitro group will go to para, since $\ce{R\bond{-}}$ groups are *weakly* activating/orthopara directing, whereas $\ce{-OH}$ is strongly activating.

Now, vigorously oxidize with acidic $\ce{KMnO4}$. The $\ce{CH2=CH-CH2\bond{-}}$ groups become $\ce{-COOH}$ groups, and the other stuff stays intact.

Now, decarboxylate it. I'm not exactly sure of it, but we can do this via:

- Treating with $\ce{NaOH}$ or soda lime.
- (or) [Treating with Vit. C](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf00029a001)

(few more from Wikipedia):

- [Barton decarboxylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton_decarboxylation)
- [(check the stuff here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decarboxylation)

The acidic and basic media may have some adverse effects on the compound, but I doubt it.

Comment: dear friend thanks for the answer, I found that ortho and para nitrophenol has two different boiling point(217 and 279 °C respectively) whether this property can be used for fractional distillation the two.

Comment: @test: For such a large difference, even simple distillation works. Fractional distillation is only _necessary_ when the difference is less that 25&deg; C (IIRC). And fractional distillation works for _any_ BP difference (not zero).

Comment: You would use an allyl halide, not an allyllithium, to react with phenol.

Comment: Steam distillation removes the ortho isomer.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done by first reating the phenol with $\ce{HNO2}$ Which gives us this

[image]

Then reacting with dil $\ce{HNO3}$ we get 90% yield of para nitro phenol

This happens because $\ce{N=O}$ has a very strong $- I$  effect thus it concentrates the electrons more towards the para position so on reacting with dil $\ce{HNO3}$ we get max yield of para

P.S - Another way of getting **only** para is using a [protecting agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_group#Alcohol_protecting_groups) but  i cant recall the reaction now. I will post it later

Comment: You can use `\ce{H2O}` in math to auto format chemicals. `\ce{N=O}` also formats the bond.

Comment: Reactions work as well `\ce{BF3 + H2O -> BOOM}` gives $\ce{BF3 + H2O -> BOOM}$ . [Full documentation.](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf)

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct, though. He wanted "only" para, not 90% para. Of course, nothing's perfect, but 10% ortho is still a lot--so I refrain from upvoting it. Otherwise, it's a nice method--I admit I wouldn't have thought of $\ce{-N=O}$-ifying(nitriting?) it :)

Answer (score 6):

The current set of solutions are rather too complicated, I think. Here's what I'd do:

- Make phenyl acetate with acetic anhydride and phenol.
- Nitrate your ester with the usual conditions; the bulky acetyl group makes *o*-nitration less likely.
- Separate out your *p*-nitrophenyl acetate
- Hydrolyze your nice ester.

There are a number of bulky *protecting groups* one could use for the phenolic -OH, but acetic anhydride is rather cheap in my neck of the woods, and it's what I'm accustomed to.

Comment: Uhh, 'the separate out' could have been done directly via distillation. I've included that in my answer, but I felt that it was cheating, hence the long 'complicated' procedure (also, I wanted to have fun)